# How to set the minimum length to 3 in the Lucene FrenchAnalyzer?

Tags: java, lucene, lexical-analysis

I can't figure out how to set the minimum character length to 3 in the Lucene French analyzer I create as below in Java:

```
private final FrenchAnalyzer analyzer = new FrenchAnalyzer();
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks,
Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FrenchAnalyzer` is declared as final, so it can't be extended. I would work around this by copying the source and adding a [`LengthFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/LengthFilter.html) to the copy.

The steps are as follows (assuming you are using the latest version of Lucene):

1. Get a copy of the source class from GitHub [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fr/FrenchAnalyzer.java).
2. Rename the class as appropriate (e.g. `CustomFrenchAnalyzer`) and change all the class's constructors accordingly.
3. Add the following import:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.LengthFilter;
```

4. In the `createComponents` and `normalize` methods, add in the new length filter. For example, assuming you want to remove words which are less than 3 characters, as per your question:

```
@Override
protected TokenStream normalize(String fieldName, TokenStream in) {
    TokenStream result = new ElisionFilter(in, DEFAULT_ARTICLES);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    // the following line is added:
    result = new LengthFilter(result, 3, 9999);
    return result;
}
```

Do the same for the `createComponents` method, also.

This way, your custom class will automatically take advantage of the other features built into the French Analyzer:

- the French elision filter
- the default set of French [stop-words](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/french_stop.txt) (bundled with the Lucene JAR).
- and so on.

And it can be constructed using any of the analyzer's non-empty constructors, if needed.

If you are not using a compatible version of Lucene, you will have to track down the relevant Git branch, or download the source JAR from the Lucene [download page](https://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html) and grab the source from there.